# How hard is it to break an 8 digit pin of AES 256 encrypted external sata enclosure?

Tags: encryption, aes, disk-encryption, decryption, sata

I am looking at external sata enclosures for 2.5" drives, there are some with keypad on them and protect the data with pin that is usually limited to around 8 digits. Drive is protected with AES 256 encryption.

How fast can this pin be cracked ? I assume in theory the keypad can be connected to a computer.

I don't know if these sata enclosures usually force a delay after some failed attempts, if someone knows please let me know.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. If these devices make any sense at all (and use the built-in encryption that modern SSDs and hard drives have):

The device's decryption key is stored within a microcontroller that simply will delete the key if you tried wrong PINs too often.

In other words: although it might maybe only take thousandth of a second to try one PIN, after three PINs (or whatever the manufacturer designed the microcontroller for), the device is bricked and there's effectively no way to recover the data.

Comment: Yes, that is the obvious expectation, but amazingly most of them have no block/delay protection when entering wrong password. I asked two persons at StarTech and both said there is no protection. So the AES 256 encryption becomes a bad joke when it is protected by an 8 digit pin. Old cell phones pins are more secure than that.